# How do I install PHP 5.5 to Homestead?

Tags: php, homestead

I upgraded my Homestead to the latest version, and this version only supports PHP 7.3, 7.2 and 7.1. I have a old project that is using PHP 5.5. How do I install PHP 5.5 to Homestead? I don't want to install multiple Homestead in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. [PHP 5.5 reached end-of-life in July 2016](https://www.php.net/eol.php).

Update your project to work on a supported version of PHP.